# How is reentrancy implemented in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

What actually happens when the same thread tries to acquire a *lock* that it already owns ?

Comment: Why the down vote ? Is this a duplicate post ?

Comment: Can you clarify: Do you mean ReentrantLock or are you referring to the fact that monitors are reentrant (synchronized blocks)?

Comment: @assylias Moot now as there are already answers under both assumptions :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I can't help being curious :-)

Comment: @assylias I meant monitors(also called locks)  are reentrant:-).

Comment: Subhra, monitors and locks are not the same thing. You acquire a *lock* on a *monitor*. Your terminology fits exactly the terminology from the Java Language Specification discussing the semantics of the `synchronized` keyword, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your question is about the semantics of the `synchronized` block/modifier. Refer to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1). If your question is about a specific implementation's way of doing it, then you need to specify the exact implementation you have in mind. But this being a well-understood technique, I don't see a reason for that.

Comment: No symantics is not the intent of this question. Anyway , thanks for answering.

Comment: So it's about the `java.util.concurrent` API? OK, then you are well-covered with the other answers. The phrase "acquire a lock" does refer to Java's first-class support for thread synchronization, though.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

> A reentrant mutual exclusion Lock with the same basic behavior and semantics as the implicit >monitor lock accessed using synchronized methods and statements, but with extended >capabilities.
>
> A ReentrantLock is owned by the thread last successfully locking, but not yet unlocking it. >A thread invoking lock will return, successfully acquiring the lock, when the lock is not >owned by another thread. The method will return immediately if the current thread already >owns the lock. This can be checked using methods isHeldByCurrentThread(), and getHoldCount().

I Agree that GrepCode explains it very well